# Is there a tool to add SafeMath to production code?

Tags: solidity, truffle, openzeppelin, embark, safemath

There are a lot of tools to prepare JavaScript/CSS code for production, e.g. to minimize, to convert ES8 code to ES5. Is there a tool to automatically apply SafeMath library to a .sol file?

The problem is that `.add()`, `.mul()`, etc. are much less readable than `+`, `-`, `+=`, etc. It takes much more time to edit and understand the source code with `.add()`'s instead of `+`'s. But the task of converting `+` to `.add()` doesn't require any intelligence and could be done by a build script. Does such a script exist (something like babel but for Solidity)?

Comment: How is that gonna help? The contract will be eventually deployed and verified with its "real" code, i.e., you'll be seeing `add` and `mul`, not `+` and `*`.

Comment: E.g. I've been developing my contract with `+` and `*` (because `+` and `*` are just faster to type than `.add`, `.mul()` and a lot of nested parentheses) and now I'm ready to deploy it. It'd take a couple of hours to replace all `+` and `-` manually.

Comment: You do realize that not necessarily should you replace every arithmetic operator in your code with a function-call, right? That could end up being a huge waste of gas. You should consider each operation separately, and determine whether or not it needs to be "secured".